# Booleans, conditional operators and autoboxing

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, boolean, conditional-operator, autoboxing

Why does this throw `NullPointerException`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Boolean b = true ? returnsNull() : false; // NPE on this line.
    System.out.println(b);
}

public static Boolean returnsNull() {
    return null;
}
```

while this doesn't

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Boolean b = true ? null : false;
    System.out.println(b); // null
}
```

?

The solution is by the way to replace `false` by `Boolean.FALSE` to avoid `null` being unboxed to `boolean` --which isn't possible. But that isn't the question. The question is *why*? Are there any references in JLS which confirms this behaviour, especially of the 2nd case?

Comment: wow, autoboxing is a endless source of ... er... surprises for the java programmer, isn't it? :-)

Comment: I had a similar problem and what suprised me was that it failed on the OpenJDK VM but worked on HotSpot VM ... Write once, run anywhere!

Answer (score 96, accepted):

**The difference is that the explicit type of the `returnsNull()` method affects the static typing of the expressions at compile time:**

```
E1: `true ? returnsNull() : false` - boolean (auto-unboxing 2nd operand to boolean)

E2: `true ? null : false` - Boolean (autoboxing of 3rd operand to Boolean)
```

See Java Language Specification, section [**15.25 Conditional Operator ? :**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

- For E1, the types of the 2nd and 3rd operands are `Boolean` and `boolean` respectively, so this clause applies:

  > If one of the second and third operands is of type boolean and the type of the other is of type Boolean, then the type of the conditional expression is boolean.

  Since the type of the expression is `boolean`, the 2nd operand must be coerced to `boolean`.  The compiler inserts auto-unboxing code to the 2nd operand (return value of `returnsNull()`) to make it type `boolean`.  This of course causes the NPE from the `null` returned at run-time.
- For E2, types of the 2nd and 3rd operands are `<special null type>` (not `Boolean` as in E1!) and `boolean` respectively, so no specific typing clause applies ([go read 'em!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)), so the final "otherwise" clause applies:

  > Otherwise, the second and third operands are of types S1 and S2 respectively. Let T1 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S1, and let T2 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S2. The type of the conditional expression is the result of applying capture conversion (§5.1.10) to lub(T1, T2) (§15.12.2.7).

  - S1 == `<special null type>` (see [§4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1))
  - S2 == `boolean`
  - T1 == box(S1) == `<special null type>` (see last item in list of boxing conversions in  [§5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7))
  - T2 == box(S2) == `Boolean
  - lub(T1, T2) == `Boolean`

  So the type of the conditional expression is `Boolean` and the 3rd operand must be coerced to `Boolean`.  The compiler inserts auto-boxing code for the 3rd operand (`false`).  The 2nd operand doesn't need the auto-unboxing as in `E1`, so no auto-unboxing NPE when `null` is returned.

---

This question needs a similar type analysis:

[Java conditional operator ?: result type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615498/java-conditional-operator-result-type)

Comment: Makes sense ... I think. The [§15.12.2.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#341287) is a pain.

Comment: It's easy ... but only in hindsight. :-)

Comment: @BertF What does the function `lub` in `lub(T1,T2)` stand for?

Comment: @Geek - lub() - least upper bound - basically the closest superclass that they have in common; since null (type "the special null type") can be implicitly converted (widened) to any type, you can consider the special null type to be a "superclass" of any type (class) for the purposes of lub().

Answer (score 29):

The line:

```
    Boolean b = true ? returnsNull() : false;
```

is internally transformed to:

```
    Boolean b = true ? returnsNull().booleanValue() : false;
```

to perform the unboxing; thus: `null.booleanValue()` will yield a NPE

This is one of the major pitfalls when using autoboxing. This behavior is indeed documented in [5.1.8 JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.8)

Edit: I believe the unboxing is due to the third operator being of boolean type, like (implicit cast added):

```
   Boolean b = (Boolean) true ? true : false;
```

Comment: Why does it try to unbox like that, when the ultimate value is a Boolean object?

Answer (score 17):

From [Java Language Specification, section 15.25](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25):

> - If one of the second and third
>     operands is of type boolean and the
>     type of the other is of type Boolean,
>     then the type of the conditional
>     expression is boolean.

So, the first example tries to call `Boolean.booleanValue()` in order to convert `Boolean` to `boolean` as per the first rule.

In the second case the first operand is of the null type, when the second is not of the reference type, so autoboxing conversion is applied:

> - Otherwise, the second and third
>     operands are of types S1 and S2
>     respectively. Let T1 be the type that
>     results from applying boxing
>     conversion to S1, and let T2 be the
>     type that results from applying boxing
>     conversion to S2. The type of the
>     conditional expression is the result
>     of applying capture conversion
>     (§5.1.10) to lub(T1, T2) (§15.12.2.7).

Comment: This answers the first case, but not the second case.

Comment: Probably there is an exception for when one of the values is `null`.

Comment: @Erick: does JLS confirm this?

Comment: Yes.  It's in the next line in the link @axtavt provided.  I updated the answer.

Comment: @Erick: I don't think it's applicable since `boolean` is not a reference type.

Comment: And may I add ... this is why you should make both sides of a ternary the same type, with explicit calls if necessary. Even if you have the specs memorized and know what will happen, the next programmer to come along and read your code might not. In my humble opinion, it would be better if the compiler just produced an error message in these situations rather than doing things that are difficult for ordinary mortals to predict. Well, maybe there are cases where the behavior is truly useful, but I haven't hit one yet.

Answer (score 0):

We can see this problem from byte code. At line 3 of main's byte code, `3: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Boolean.booleanValue:()Z`, the boxing Boolean of value null, `invokevirtual` the method `java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue`, it will throw NPE of course.

```
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]) throws java.lang.Exception;
      descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
      flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
      Code:
        stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
           0: invokestatic  #2                  // Method returnsNull:()Ljava/lang/Boolean;
           3: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Boolean.booleanValue:()Z
           6: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Boolean.valueOf:(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
           9: astore_1
          10: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
          13: aload_1
          14: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
          17: return
        LineNumberTable:
          line 3: 0
          line 4: 10
          line 5: 17
      Exceptions:
        throws java.lang.Exception

    public static java.lang.Boolean returnsNull();
      descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Boolean;
      flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
      Code:
        stack=1, locals=0, args_size=0
           0: aconst_null
           1: areturn
        LineNumberTable:
          line 8: 0
```