# java: weird NullPointerException in ternary operator (? : )

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ternary-operator

Please consider this code snippet:

```
private static void doSomething(Double avg, Double min, Double sd) {
    final Double testMin;
    if (avg != null) {
        testMin = Math.max(min, avg - 3 * sd);
    } else {
        testMin = min;
    }
    System.out.println("testMin=" + testMin);

    final Double verwachtMin = avg != null ? Math.max(min, avg - 3 * sd) : min;
    System.out.println("verwachtMin=" + verwachtMin);
}
```

As far as I know (and for what my IDE can tell me), the variables `testMin` and `verwachtMin` should be equivalent.

As you might expect, I'd rather write the last 2 lines than the first 7. However, when I pass 3 null values to this method, I get an NPE on the calculation of the `verwachtMin` variable.

Does anyone know how this can happen? Does the ternary operator evaluate the 2nd part, even when the condition is not `true`?

(Java version 1.6.0_21)

Comment: Related: [Booleans, conditional operators and autoboxing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882095/booleans-conditional-operators-and-autoboxing)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try:

```
final Double verwachtMin = avg != null ? new Double(Math.max(min, avg - 3 * sd)) : min;
```

or

```
final Double verwachtMin = avg != null ? Double.valueOf(Math.max(min, avg - 3 * sd)) : min;
```

The types of the alternate sides of the ternary operator were `double` and `Double`, which means that the `Double` gets unboxed to `double`, and then on assignment we have a boxing from `double` to `Double`. If the value of `min` is `null` then the unboxing NPEs.

Comment: Thanks, should've known this.

Comment: Isn't that actually a bug? As far as I can tell the logical thing would be for Java to promote the double to a Double since the other value is already a Double. I guess it has to behave like this due to specifications/legacy code, but it does not make much sense...

Comment: @MarkusBarthlen You wouldn't want to have values unnecessarily boxed as there is the memory management overhead. Perhaps there could be some kind of target typing rule, but the mix of overloading, target typing and the rest of the type system is somewhat overcomplicated even as it stands.

Comment: If the other value is a Double, you have to take into account that it could be null. Even if you would be saving memory this way.

Answer (score 4):

> Does the ternary operator evaluate the 2nd part, even when the condition
>   is not true

No - but it evaluates the 3rd part and I think in this case it tries to autounbox `min` (leading to the NPE) because the return type of `Math.max()` is primitive `double` and determines the return type of the entire expression.

Autoboxing/-unboxing is of the devil.

Comment: "The return type of the entire expression" isn't what causes the unboxing - it's that `Math.max()` takes `double`s, not `Double`s.

Comment: @Matt: I don't think the parameters to `Math.max()` are evaluated when the guard expression is `false`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by [**autoboxing**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)*, not by the ternary operator. You are using the [`Double`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) wrapper type rather than the `double` primitive type. Because [`Math.max()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max%28double,%20double%29) expects `double` parameters, not `Double`s, there is an invisible call to [`Double#doubleValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleValue%28%29) before the values are passed to `Math.max()`. However, you can't call a method on a `null` object - hence the `NullPointerException`.

Why are you using `Double` instead of `double` in the first place? A primitive-type variable  (such as a `double`) simply cannot be `null`.

---

*Well, autounboxing, in this case

Comment: I'm using `Double` instead of `double`, because I know it might be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-unboxing causes the problem. Similar question has been asked before .. You sould use double instead of Double to solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

`Math.max(min, avg - 3 * sd)` here `min`, `avg` and `sd` are autounboxed from Double to double which when one of them is null causes an NPE.