# NullPointerException in ternary expression with null Long

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Why does the following line of code produce a `NullPointerException`?

```
Long v = 1 == 2 ? Long.MAX_VALUE : (Long) null;
```

I understand that unboxing is being performed on `null`, but why?

Note that

```
Long v = (Long) null;
```

Does not produce the Exception.

Comment: You do a v=((1==2)?Long.MAX_VALUE : (Long) null); this is always false, so you always try to cast null to Long. This seems not to be allowed and throws your Exception.

Comment: Why would you have such a line of code?  Intellectual curiosity or is it a snippet from actual production code?

Comment: @Paul and evildead, looks like example code to demonstrate ordering of unboxing.

Comment: It has everything to do with http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25

Comment: @Paul, This is from production, but simplified to produce the exception in simple code.

Comment: Why don't you break apart the ternary operator into if/then/else?  That may help you puzzle this out.

Comment: It's from production?  Once again, readability wins out over cleverness...

Comment: @Paul If you break it out in to if/then/else theproblem goes away.

Comment: Breaking it into if then else causes the exception to go away. I'm just wondering why the ternary syntax causes this exception.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882095/booleans-conditional-operators-and-autoboxing Solution is by the way to move that cast to your `Long.MAX_VALUE` as that returns `long`.

Comment: @Tom, then they should remove all such instances from the code, make the guy who wrote them buy donuts for the team, then read up on order of precedence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So it looks obvious that you only have to box if the condition is true, and there should be no boxing if the condition is false. However the ternary operator expression must have a particular **static** type. So we have `Long` and `long`. The JLS states that the result will be the primitive (just as well - imagine if the operator was, say, `+` or even `==`). So the ternary operator will force the unboxing, and only then does the assignment cause a boxing.

If you were to replace the code with the equivalent `if-else`, then you'd just have an assignment from `long` to `Long` and from `Long` to `Long`, which wouldn't have any unboxing and so run fine.

IIRC, this is covered is Bloch & Gafter's Java Puzzlers.

Answer (score 0):

From the [JSL](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25)

> 1. If the second and third operands have the same type (which may be the null type), then that is the type of the conditional expression.
> 2. If one of the second and third operands is of type `boolean` and the type of the other is of type `Boolean`, then the type of the
>      conditional expression is `boolean`.

In following statement the type of second operand is `long` and third is `Long`.

```
Long v = 1 == 2 ? Long.MAX_VALUE :  (Long) null;
```

This will work if an expression is true.

```
Long v= 1 == 1 ?  Long.MAX_VALUE : (Long) null;
```

Or you may cast it.

```
Long v= 1 == 2 ?  Long.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE) : (Long) null;
```

Comment: Yes, I know it's doing unboxing, and that you can't unbox null. I was asking why it is trying to perform unboxing in this case.

Comment: That's not entirely correct.  He's trying to unbox a null `Long` object; the cast is not the problem.  You can cast `null` to any type of object, see the Java Language Spec [section 5.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.5), under "If a cast to a reference type is not a compile-time error, there are several cases:"