# Why NullPointerException occur in short IF

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I written short Java code which cause NullPointerException. Does anybody have explanation for this? Code:

```
int val = 2;
Boolean result = (val == 0) ? false : ((val == 1) ? true : null);
```

Also following (simplified version) code will cause NullPointerException:

```
Object result = (false) ? false : (false ? true : null);
```

But this:

```
int val = 2;
Boolean result = (val == 0) ? Boolean.FALSE : ((val == 1) ? true : null);
```

and this:

```
Object result = (false) ? Boolean.FALSE : (false ? true : null);
```

or this:

```
Object result = (false) ? (Boolean)false : (false ? true: null);
```

doesn't?

Comment: `((val == 1) ? true : null)` here change `null` to `false`??

Comment: Use `boolean` rather than `Boolean` to avoid many NullPointerExceptions

Comment: @TheNewIdiot That doesn't make a difference for this case

Comment: It is probably `null.booleanValue()` which throws NPE.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot I wanted have possibility to have three values in Boolean: true, false and null for error detection.

Answer (score 4):

I think what's happening is that `((val == 1) ? true : null)` always returns `null` and it then tries to unbox that into a `boolean`.  That causes a null pointer exception.

After I said this, @JonSkeet marked your question as a duplicate because of [NullPointerException in ternary expression with null Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514466/nullpointerexception-in-ternary-expression-with-null-long)  The answer there has a much more detailed explanation.

Comment: So why changing `false` to `Boolean.FALSE` in example fix NPE?

Answer (score 0):

int val = 2;

boolean result = (val==o)? false:true; // remove null from code and replace it with true.

Answer (score -1):

In java, `boolean` allows only `true` and `false` but Boolean allows `true` `false` and `NULL`

Comment: so, whats the reason for NPE?

Comment: Oh snap, wanted this to be a comment and not an answer. @___@