# Utility method to convert Boolean into boolean and handle null in Java

Tags: java, boolean, utility-method

Is there a utility method in Java which converts `Boolean` into `boolean` and automatically handles null reference to `Boolean` as false?

Comment: Ermm ... it is one line of code ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Booleans, conditional operators and autoboxing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882095/booleans-conditional-operators-and-autoboxing)

Comment: @StephenC Yeah ..but OP might searching for a smart line of code ;) (look at skeets solution)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

How about:

```
boolean x = Boolean.TRUE.equals(value);
```

? That's a single expression, which will only evaluate to `true` if `value` is non-null and a true-representing `Boolean` reference.

Answer (score 9):

On java 8 you can do:

```
static boolean getPrimitive(Boolean value) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(value).orElse(false);
}
```

You can also do:

```
static boolean getPrimitive(Boolean value) {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean("" + value);
}
```

Comment: These both allocate an unnecessary object. [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24950467) doesn't.

Comment: both are 'valid' and memory overheads are negligible.(The first one is simply an optional return, if its really so bad?)
I am very well aware of 'jon skeets' answer, but this is more to demonstrate what is possible, (more so with OP's context of automatically handling null reference for Boolean).

Comment: One unnecessary object allocation per call is not negligible in code that is called, in a practical use case, once per boolean column, per row, per database fetch. Yes, the JVM *might* be able to optimize away the Optional via escape analysis. But it also *might* not. Why use a longer, less clear, allocating idiom when a shorter, clearer, non-allocating alternative exists?

Comment: with all due respect, please refer the OP, it didnt ask for most optimum way to do it, but the way in which null is handled automatically. Please take things in context.  

By your reasoning I suppose you are advocating not to use Optional?

PS: The accepted answer is the best fit.

Comment: I have no problem with Optional when used as intended, a return type for methods which may or may not return a result.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether it exists or not. I'd write a one liner like:

```
public static boolean getPrimitiveBoolean(Boolean bool) {    
   return bool == null ? false : bool.booleanValue();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a ready-made utility ? Then I think Commons-Lang [BooleanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html) is the answer. It has a method 
[toBoolean(Boolean bool)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html#toBoolean(java.lang.Boolean)).

Answer (score 1):

If you're [golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com), an explicit null check followed by [automatic unboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27647772) is shorter than the [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24950467).

```
boolean b=o!=null&&o; // For golfing purposes only, don't use in production code
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a method you could write that would do the trick. This would return false if the Boolean is null.

```
public static boolean toBooleanDefaultIfNull(Boolean bool) {
    if (bool == null) return false;
    return bool.booleanValue();
}
```

Comment: The return bool.booleanValue() ? true : false; is pretty useless, just do return bool.booleanValue() ;)

Comment: Skeet's answer is much better than this, but I'll change mine with your suggestion anyways.