# Why can Object[] store primitives?

Tags: java, primitive, autoboxing

`Object[]` can store any object from any class because every class in Java extends `java.lang.Object`.

I don't think primitives extend from `Object`, so why can we store them like the following?

```
Object[] obj_arr = {1, 2, 1.2, 'a', false, new MyClass(), null};
```

The question is why can primitives be stored in an Object array and did **Auto boxing** happen or not in the above code?

Comment: Pretty sure you could check the auto boxing yourself  using `instanceof`, no?

Comment: When you run the code, autoboxing will change `1` and `2` to their wrapper types.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647407/why-do-we-use-autoboxing-and-unboxing-in-java

Comment: @bcsb1001 Thanks for editing my post :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primitive types get auto-boxed into their respective wrapper types, so for instance: `1` becomes `Integer.valueOf(1)` and that's an instance of the `Integer` class which extends from `Object`, hence it can be stored into an `Object[]`. The same thing happens for the other primitives - instances of `Double`, `Character` and `Boolean` are used in place of the corresponding primitive values.

Comment: Actually, autoboxing doesn't replace `1` by `new Integer(1)` but by `Integer.valueOf(1)`, which may return a cached `Integer` object.