# Java objects and primitive types variables confused

Tags: java

I am confused between these three codes

```
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6;
    int c = 5;
```

and

```
    Integer x = new Integer(5);
    Integer y = new Integer(6);
    Integer z = new Integer(5);
```

and

```
    Integer i = 5;
    Integer j = 6;
    Integer k = 5;
```

I know that the first one are some variables that contain values and the second one are some variables reference to some different objects, but what is the third one? I know that they are reference data types.

But I can't understand why and how many objects created... if any!

Comment: the third cases uses autoboxing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647407/why-do-we-use-autoboxing-and-unboxing-in-java

Comment: in this case this there are 2 different references, in a different case there could be 3. [refering to Integer caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131136/integers-caching-in-java)

Comment: The third case is extra tricky because of the `IntegerCache` built into the `Integer` class. The third case creates no new objects at all - it instead initialises `i` and `j` to the reference to the cached `Integer` object that holds the value `5`, and `j` to the reference to the cached `Integer` object that holds the value `6`. This means that `i == k` returns `true`, whereas `x == z` returns `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Integer` is a (wrapper) class name and so the variables of this type are objects. When `x` is assigned the value of `new Integer(5)` then, ethically, you cannot use x directly for mathematical operations. To use x in operations, you have to use the wrapper class method `intValue()` to get x's value in numeric (primitive) form from object form.

Eg.:

```
Integer x = new Integer(5);
int my_x = x.intValue();
int y = 10 + my_x; //y = 15
```

However, using x directly in mathematical ops would not produce an error and, in fact, will produce the same output as going through the above step will. This is because the JVM **implicitly** converts the object to primitive data value and this process is called **Auto boxing**. The inverse, when implicitly done, is called **Un-boxing**. Therefore, in the above example, you can also do this:

```
Integer x = new Integer(5);
int y = 10 + x; //y = 15;
```

Hope you now understand.

Comment: "then, ethically, you cannot use x directly for mathematical operations. " -- Really?  Ethically? I wasn't aware that coding in Java required a particular direction on ones moral compass.

Comment: I said ethical because that's how the teacher teaches right? You are first instructed to use `intValue()` and then are introduced to autoboxing and unboxing. :-P

Comment: I use x for great justice.  Take off every Zig.

Comment: Yes .. that's it .. thank you

Answer (score 1):

`int a = 5;` stores a primitive int

`Integer x = new Integer(5)` stores a primitive int wrapped in an `Integer` object.

`Integer i = 5;` Also stores a primitive int wrapped in an `Integer` object, but the compiler takes care of wrapping it for you. This is called "autoboxing"

You can also do the reverse and write `int foo = new Integer(5)`. This is called "auto unboxing".

Comment: Great answer, thank you