# What good does using new Integer here do?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackIntro {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stack clapper = new Stack();

        for( int i=0; i<11; i++){
            clapper.push(i);
        }

        while(!clapper.isEmpty()){
            System.out.print ( clapper.pop() );     //FILO
            System.out.print ( ',' );
            if(clapper.size()==1){
                System.out.print(clapper.pop());    //FILO
                System.out.println("...");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Lift-off.");
        clapper.removeAllElements();
    }
}
```

So basically I just wanted to see how numbers go in and out of a stack. The FILO comment shows this. I was told that I should actually change line 8 :

```
clapper.push(i); //previous

clapper.push(new Integer(i)); //new
```

I don't understand what this would accomplish, or the difference between the two.

Comment: Have you ever heard about `Autoboxing`?

Comment: @user2004685 What is that?

Comment: @ChuckBIhekwaba As you have asked, here is a great answer on the topic: *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647407/why-do-we-use-autoboxing-and-unboxing-in-java*

Comment: the better advice would have been to use `Integer.valueOf(i)` which may save some memory when numbers get repeated. This is not the case in your example, but can happen IRL.

Comment: The only slight difference is that `new Integer(i)` always creates a new Integer, whereas the autoboxed approach compiles to `Integer.valueOf(i)`, which caches values at least the values in [-128, 127].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although due to autoboxing both lines of code result in an `Integer` object with value `1` being pushed on the stack, the two lines do **not** have exctly the same effect.

Autoboxing uses the Integer *cache*, which is required by the JLS for values from `-128` to `127`, such that the resulting `Integer` instance is the *same* instance for any value in that range.

However, invoking the `int` constructor creates a *new* `Integer` instance every time it's called.

Consider:

```
Integer a = 1; // autoboxing
Integer b = 1; // autoboxing
System.out.println(a == b); // true
Integer c = new Integer(1);
Integer d = new Integer(1);
System.out.println(c == d); // false
```

This distinction may cause different behaviour in your program if you use `==` (object identity) when comparing values pushed and popped to/from the stack instead of `equals()`.

Comment: You are technically right, but your answer ends up also being problematic, quite possibly more problematic than my answer: if he uses object identity when comparing values, he is going to run into serious trouble as soon as he uses a value outside of the cached range.  So, the right answer is that there is a slight difference which will only be noticed if he makes the mistake of using object identity equality comparisons.  I can delete my answer and you can fix yours, or you can delete yours and I can fix mine, I leave it up to you.

Comment: @Mike the question is not about what's "right" or "better". It was about "what is the *difference*". Both answers have value to readers btw.

Comment: Yes, and that's why as I said you are technically correct.  You pinpointed the difference, which I forgot.  But at the same time you are *possibly* exposing the OP to a world of pain.

Comment: OK, I agree both answers are useful, especially if read together with the comments.  I am not going to do anything.

Answer (score 4):

This would not accomplish much, very possibly not anything at all.

The idea is that `clapper.push(T)` accepts an object, but `i` is not an object, it is a primitive, so the compiler will automatically box it into an `Integer` object before passing it to `clapper.push()`.

Auto-boxing was not a feature of java from the beginning, so there may still exist some old-timers who are uncomfortable with it.  But that should be entirely their own problem.  Java has come a long way since then.  Auto-boxing is taken for granted, we do not even give it any thought anymore.

Passing `i` and having the compiler auto-box it is exactly the same as as passing `new Integer(i)`.

Comment: Actually, this answer is wrong, especially the last sentence. Yes it autoboxes, but **no** the two lines are **not** "exactly the same" - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40117000/256196)

Comment: @Bohemian you are right, but see my comment on your answer.