# Java - How do if statements know the values of a Boolean object?

Tags: java, object, boolean

How do if statements recognize the `Boolean` object as a `boolean`?  such as:

```
Boolean b = new Boolean(true);
if(b){
    System.out.println("true!");
} else {
    System.out.println("false!");
}
```

This would print true, but how is `Boolean` recognized?

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: BTW You should use a primitive instead of a wrapper where possible esp if you are not expecting the value to be null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called **autoboxing** and works for primitive types in Java, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647407/why-do-we-use-autoboxing-and-unboxing-in-java) for a brief SO explanation or [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for the official documentation. Java automatically converts the object representation `Boolean` into the corresponding primitive type `boolean` and back. The first is called **unboxing** and the latter **boxing**.