# is the keyword "new" in Java necessary

Tags: java, oop

The two following codes give me the same result even though only one of them use the keyword `new`:

Code 1:

```
Integer test = new Integer(3);
```

Code 2:

```
Integer test = 3;
```

From an OOP perspective, is there anything different between the two codes?

Comment: Probably worth updating your question title.  If it were literally true, then you'd be asking about the code `Integer test = Integer(3);`.

Comment: The line in code is the same as above: Integer test = 3;

Comment: That only applies to *some* types (such as `String` and primitive wrappers), but not *all* types.

Comment: You should look into autoboxing if you want to know why your example works.

Comment: From an _**OOP**_ perspective there _is_ a difference; from a _Java_ perspective there is no difference because of [Syntactic Sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) and [autoboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27647407/17300)

Comment: In `test = 3;`, the `3` will come out of the constant pool, whereas using `new` will create a brand new reference.

Comment: The second line is a special case. It only works because Java offers **auto-boxing** for primitive types (`int`, `short`, `long`, `byte`, `char`, `float`, `double`). It won't work for Objects. It basically means that Java will automatically convert `3` to an `Integer` representing `3` if needed, like here. And also vice versa if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instantiating variables with **new keyword** allocating the variable in the heap memory as a new object but if you used **direct initialization** the variable will be stored into the **JVM pooled memory** and if you declared a new variable with the same value it will reference the value for the first variable , there is two benefits of using direct initializing :

1. Better performance
2. Less memory needed for the program requirements

**Note :** you should be aware of using direct initializing as the JVM pooled memory has limited size  .

Answer (score 2):

What is actually happening here is the compiler is generating the same byte code for the line `test = 3;` as if you wrote `test = Integer.valueOf(3);`. In Java, this is called autoboxing. It allows primitive types to be converted to an Object (reference type) and vice-versa without explicitly declaring so in your code. You can read more about it here: [Autoboxing and Unboxing at the Oracle Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

In Java, at some point, almost all instances of objects are created with the `new` keyword, and it is necessary to use `new` to call a constructor, which will allocate memory for and initialize the fields of an object; whether it's done explicitly by the programmer or behind the scenes is another matter. For example, `Integer.valueOf(3)` *could* create a new instance of Integer representing the primitive int 3 when called, but it could also return an old reference to a previously created instance of Integer representing 3, since instances of the Integer class are immutable. Either way, you'll get a reference to an Integer object representing the primitive int value 3.