# Preferred usage of ObjectArrayList over ArrayList

Tags: java, fastutil

I am very new to Java. I have recently come across **fastutil** and found ObjectArrayList class.

Is there any difference in performance if ObjectArrayList is used instead of ArrayList? What are the use cases for using ObjectArrayList?

Answer (score 4):

According to fastutil [documentation](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/ObjectArrayList.html)

> A type-specific array-based list; provides some additional methods that use polymorphism to avoid (un)boxing.

There is a performance benefit to fastutil's implementation in cases where [(un)boxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647407/why-do-we-use-autoboxing-and-unboxing-in-java) takes place.

The `ObjectArrayList` is backed by a generic type array. Whereas an `ArrayList` is backed by `Object[]` Really the performance between the two would be nominal. However FWIW, looks like this library provides primitive backed arrays `IntArrayList` `DoubleArrayList` where these boxing claims would actually see visible benefits in large datasets.

However, if you're new to Java. I'd highly recommend getting familiar with [java.util.ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) before seeking out other variants.In most cases, taking the standard outweighs the performance benefit.

Comment: It seems to be a bogus claim, though. Can you give an example of a situation where an ArrayList would use boxing but an ObjectArrayList would not?

Comment: Well... you can't create an ArrayList with a primitive. `ArrayList<int> list`... which means that list.add(1) would have no choice but to be autoboxed. I haven't scrubbed through the source code and referencing their documentation. So the claim could in fact be bogus

Comment: of course, but the same rule applies to ObjectArrayList.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. But I was really looking at anything special that fastutils might be doing since ArrayList is already there.

Comment: Updated answer to answer the difference between the ObjectArrayList and ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You should not be concerned with performance when you start learning a new language. Focus on the basics. Write code that runs, and then write code that is useful. Speed and efficiency only matters when the code you write affects the world around you (such as writing code for work). Do not worry about fastutil and ObjectArrayList. Finish your application with ArrayList and if your app is too slow for you only then should you find something faster.

Comment: I have language constraints of using Java. And I have very limited time budget to process - well within 150 micros. I am using benchmarking tools (like JMH) to assess it anyway but it I wanted to know if anyone have any idea about what could be a reason as to why fastutil will go ahead with its own version of ArrayList