# Java function returning int instead of Integer

Tags: java, integer, int

Folks, I'm writing a resource manager which can manager different types of resources. Resources can be integers or some custom types. So, I defined an interface like this:

```
public interface ResourceManagerInterface<R> {
    /**
     * allocateResource:
     * Allocate a resource from the resource pool
     * @return
     */
    R allocateResource() throws ResourceUnavailableException;

    /**
     * freeResource:
     * Deallocate/Return/Free a resource and make it available in the pool.
     * @param resource
     */
    void freeResource(R resource) throws InvalidResourceException;
}
```

One of the implementors of this interface manages resource of type "int". Since I could not do:

```
public class NumericResourceManager implements ResourceManagerInterface<int>
```

I ended up doing:

```
public class NumericResourceManager implements ResourceManagerInterface<Integer>
```

Note: used "Integer" instead of "int".

I had a piece of code like this:

```
@Override
    public Integer allocateResource() throws ResourceUnavailableException {
        try {
            return internalToExternal(firstAvailableResource());
        } catch (ResourceUnavailableException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

The function internalToExternal() returns an "int" and NOT an "Integer".

Questions:
1. Is there an automatic conversion from "int" to "Integer"?

2. I use the interface like below:

   int someint = someManager.allocateResource();

That is, I'm getting the return value in an "int" and not "Integer". This is also working fine.

Since it works, I'm a bit confused if this is safe and I can leave this as is?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is called [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647407/why-do-we-use-autoboxing-and-unboxing-in-java?rq=1) has some additional good information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the conversion from `Integer` to `int` will happen automatically as was mentioned in the comments. This is called (automatic) unboxing.

However, if the Integer to be unboxed is `null`, the unboxing will throw a `NullPointerException`. So keep that in mind for your other code.