# Scala cast to generic type

Tags: scala, casting, type-erasure, boxing

I'm confused about the generic type. I expect that `2.asInstanceOf[A]` is cast to the type `A`, meanwhile, it's cast to `Int`.
Besides that, the input is `java.lang.Long` whereas the output is a list of `Int` (according to the definition the input and the output should be the same type). Why is that?

```
def whatever[A](x: A): List[A] = {
  val two = 2.asInstanceOf[A]
  val l = List(1.asInstanceOf[A],2.asInstanceOf[A])

  println(f"Input type inside the function for 15L: ${x.getClass}")
  println(f"The class of two: ${two.getClass}, the value of two: $two")
  println(f"The class of the first element of l: ${l.head.getClass}, first element value: ${l.head}")
  l
}

println(f"Returned from whatever function: ${whatever(15L)}")
```

the outupt:

```
Input type inside the function for 15L: class java.lang.Long
The class of two: class java.lang.Integer, the value of two: 2
The class of the first element of l: class java.lang.Integer, first element value: 1
Returned from whatever function: List(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 16):

`a.asInstanceOf[B]` means:

Dear compiler;

Please forget what you think the type of `a` is. I know better. I know that if `a` isn't *actually* type `B` then my program could blow up, but I'm really very smart and that's not going to happen.

Sincerely yours, Super Programmer

In other words `val b:B = a.asInstanceOf[B]` won't create a new variable of type `B`, it will create a new variable that will be treated *as if* it were type `B`. If the actual underlying type of `a` is compatible with type `B` then everything is fine. If `a`'s real type is incompatible with `B` then things blow up.

Comment: This is the sort of answer that makes me wish I had more than one vote :)

Comment: One up! for such an intriguing approach as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens). For the purposes *of type checking* `2` is cast to `A`; but at a later compilation stage `A` is erased to `Object`, so your code becomes equivalent to

```
def whatever(x: Object): List[Object] = {
  val two = 2.asInstanceOf[Object]
  val l = List(1.asInstanceOf[Object],2.asInstanceOf[Object])

  println(f"Input type inside the function for 15L: ${x.getClass}")
  println(f"The class of two: ${two.getClass}, the value of two: $two")
  println(f"The class of the first element of l: ${l.head.getClass}, first element value: ${l.head}")
  l
}
```

`2.asInstanceOf[Object]` is a [boxing operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647407/why-do-we-use-autoboxing-and-unboxing-in-java) returning a `java.lang.Integer`.

If you try to actually *use* the return value as a `List[Long]` you'll eventually get a `ClassCastException`, e.g.

```
val list = whatever(15L)
val x = list(0)
```

`x` will be inferred to be `Long` and a cast inserted to unbox the expected `java.lang.Long`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @jwvh is on point. Here I'll only add a solution in case you want to fix the problem of safely converting an `Int` to an `A` in `whatever`, without knowing what `A` is. This is of course only possible if you provide a way to build a particular `A` from an `Int`. We can do this in using a type-class:

```scala
trait BuildableFromInt[+A] {
  def fromInt(i: Int): A
}
```

Now you only have to implicitly provide `BuildableFromInt` for any type `A` you wish to use in `whatever`:

```scala
object BuildableFromInt {
    implicit val longFromInt: BuildableFromInt[Long] = Long.box(_)
}
```

and now define whatever to only accept compliant types `A`:

```scala
def whatever[A : BuildableFromInt](x: A): List[A] = {
  val two = implicitly[BuildableFromInt[A]].fromInt(2)
  // Use two like any other "A"
  // ...
}
```

Now whatever can be used with any type for which a `BuildableFromInt` is available.