# Why does array.sort not work by an array like this?

Tags: java, arrays

I've just started programming around 2 weeks ago so please don't be too strict :)

I tried to solve a programming exercise to print the 3 largest elememts of an Array but the .sort Method

reports an error and I don't know why. It seems like I have declared my Array in the wrong way but I can't spot the mistake.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] elements = {1, 4, 17, 7, 25, 3, 100};
    int k = 3;
    System.out.println("Original Array: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elements));
    System.out.println(k +" largest elements of the said array are:");
    Arrays.sort(elements, Collections.reverseOrder());         
   for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) 
      System.out.print(elements[i] + " ");
}
```

}

Comment: [Sort arrays of primitive types in descending order](//stackoverflow.com/q/215271)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers addressed on how to reverse your primitive `int` array, but according to your problem question, it seems you do not need to reverse the array at all.

Simply iterate through your array beginning at the end by changing your `for` conditions:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int [] elements = {1, 4, 17, 7, 25, 3, 100};
    int k = 3;
    System.out.println("Original Array: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elements));
    System.out.println(k +" largest elements of the said array are:");
    Arrays.sort(elements);         
    for (int i = elements.length - 1; i > elements.length - k; i--) 
      System.out.print(elements[i] + " ");
}
```

**Output:**

```
Original Array: 
[1, 4, 17, 7, 25, 3, 100]
3 largest elements of the said array are:
100 25 17
```

Answer (score 5):

Because the integers are [unboxed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27647772/4417924) and are not objects. They need to be boxed, i.e Integer.

Unboxed

```java
int [] elements = {1, 4, 17, 7, 25, 3, 100};
```

Boxed

```java
Integer [] elements = {1, 4, 17, 7, 25, 3, 100};
```

### Using Java 8 Streams

```java
       int[] elements = { 1, 4, 17, 7, 25, 3, 100 };

       int[] sortedUnboxed = IntStream.of(elements)
                .boxed()
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .mapToInt(value -> value)
                .toArray();

        Integer[] sortedBoxed = IntStream.of(elements)
                .boxed()
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Answer (score 4):

`int[]` as Collections.reverseOrder doesn't work for primitive types. Please use `Integer` instead. It will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the definition of reverseOrder: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-collections-reverseorder-method

It will tell you that it looks like this:

```
public static <T> Comparator<T> reverseOrder()
```

the `<T>` is the generic template. Primitives cannot be used as generic types, see [Why don't Java Generics support primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types)

`int` is primitive type. Luckily `Integer` is a wrapper class around `int` and you can use it as generic. The rest is homework for the student.

I feel your pain that `int` cannot be a generic, but it is how it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to stick with int, just sort it and print out the last three:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int [] elements = {1, 4, 17, 7, 25, 3, 100};
    int k = 3;
    System.out.println("Original Array: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elements));
    System.out.println(k +" largest elements of the said array are:");
    Arrays.sort(elements);         
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
      System.out.print(elements[elements.length - 1 - i] + " ");
}
```