# Double ternary Integer initiation causes a null pointer

Tags: java

Why is this fine with x being set to null:

```
boolean condition1 = false;
Integer x = condition1 ? 1 : null;
```

And this fine with x being set to 2:

```
boolean condition1 = false, condition2 = true;
Integer x = condition1 ? 1 : condition2? 2 : null;
```

But this, where x should be set to null causes a java.lang.NullPointerException

```
boolean condition1 = false, condition2 = false;
Integer x = condition1 ? 1 : condition2 ? 2 : null;
```

A solution is to use:

```
Integer x = condition1 ? (Integer)1 : condition2 ? 2 : null;
```

But I'm not very clear on why a single ternary operator works fine, but not a double.

Comment: Basically, you're unboxing the null as an `int`. See the duplicate for more details.

Comment: Question with six upvotes ? Duplicate of another ? weird

Comment: It's certainly closely related.  But I don't think that other question fully deals with this case.  It certainly requires some deeper analysis to see whether the solutions there actually apply here.  So I've voted to re-open.  I think @JonSkeet has been just a little too enthusiastic here.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Put it this way: I think if you expand this into multiple statements, you'll end up with one statement which is exactly the situation in the duplicate.

Comment: @sankrish: Why is that odd? I see duplicates with upvotes all the time.

Comment: @JonSkeet Might be to your experience Jon . odd to me as i am a novice here :)

Comment: @sankrish: Basically it's a matter of "Just because 6 people haven't seen the duplicate before doesn't mean it doesn't exist" :)

Comment: @JonSkeet i agree with you :) thanks for your time

Comment: Yes, @JonSkeet, I see what you're saying, but I don't think it's quite that straightforward; there are definitely a couple of steps required to get from here to there.  In my opinion, it's different enough to be a separate question.

Comment: And I've just noticed that you have written an excellent answer.  Here, have an upvote to add to your collection.

Answer (score 1):

(I still think this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882095/booleans-conditional-operators-and-autoboxing) after you've done a bit of unpacking, but hey...)

Expand the one statement into two:

```
// Not exactly the same, but close...
Integer tmp = condition2 ? 2 : null;
Integer x = condition1 ? 1 : (int) tmp;
```

That's not exactly the same because it evaluates `condition2 ? 2 : null` even when `condition1` is false - you could model it with a method call instead, but in the case you're worrying about, both `condition1` and `condition2` are false.

Now, you may ask why we've got the cast to `int` here. That's because of [JLS 15.25.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2):

> The type of a numeric conditional expression is determined as follows:
>
> - ...
> - If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.
> - ...

We have `int` and `Integer`, so this matches for `T = int`... and the result of the "inner" conditional expression is unboxed if necessary... and that's what's causing a problem.

Casting the `1` to `Integer` changes this so that the type of the outer expression is `Integer` too (because both the second and third operands then have type `Integer`) so there's no unboxing.

Note that in our expansion, `tmp` is an `Integer`, and that really is the type of the "inner" conditional expression, because the type of the third operand is the null type, not `Integer`. You can make it fail with just the one conditional too:

```
Integer bang = false ? 2 : (Integer) null;
```

Basically, a conditional operator with second and third operands of type `int` and `Integer` respectively will perform unboxing of the third operand (and the result is type `int`), but a conditional operator with second and third operands of type `int` and `null` respectively will *not* unbox, and the result type is `Integer`.

Comment: What happens in the first example, then?

Comment: @user2357112: That's using the null type, not `Integer`, as the type of the third operand. I've just edited something into the answer, at the bottom - see if that helps.

Comment: It helps. Looks like your dupe candidate explains it, too. That's a really weird edge case. I wonder if anything prevented them from designing the language so `false ? 2 : (Integer) null` and `false ? 2 : null` behave the same, or if it was simply a mistake.

Comment: @user2357112: Most of the language is designed so that autounboxing happens when you've got one `int` and one `Integer`, so it's not particularly surprising from that perspective. The language *could* use the null type as `Integer` and unbox then too, but then it would *always* fail, which would be odd...

Comment: Looks like it's a choice between two sources of confusion.