# NullPointerException in method returning type Object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Why does the following throw a NullPointerException? :

```
public static Object myTest() { 
    boolean x = false; 
    boolean y = false; 
    return x && y ? new Object() : x ? x : y ? y : null;
}

public static void main(String [ ] args) {
    myTest(); 
}
```

I know if i do either of the following the code will not throw a NullPointerException:

**A)**

```
public static Object myTest() { 
    boolean x = false; 
    boolean y = false; 
    return x && y ? new Object() : x ? x : y ? y : (Object) null;
}

public static void main(String [ ] args) {
    myTest(); 
}
```

**B)**

```
public static Object myTest() { 
    Boolean x = false; 
    Boolean y = false; 
    return x && y ? new Object() : x ? x : y ? y : null;
}

public static void main(String [ ] args) {
    myTest(); 
}
```

Also, if i change the code completely and do the following it works:

```
public static Object myTest() { 
    boolean x = false; 
    boolean y = false; 

    if(x && y) {
        return new Object(); 
    } else if(x) {
        return x; 
    } else if(y) {
        return y;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String [ ] args) {
    myTest(); 
}
```

I guess the compiler is doing some sort of an optimization and somehow messing things up? I'm assuming it's some sort of a casting problem, but why would it throw a NullPointerException in that case instead of a ClassCastException? Any information as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's throwing a NullPointerException because there's a null pointer somewhere in that godawful mess.

Comment: That's what I thought initially but I think it's worth looking at, so +1

Comment: @laune, it does throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I think this should be logged as a [bug report](http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/)?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi the ability of a developer to write incorrect code is not a bug.

Comment: You can simplify code reproducing your problem with only `return (x ? x : (y ? y : null));`, so for simplicity consider removing `x && y ? new Object() :`

Comment: @iheanyi that is not an incorrect code. It's valid. The compiler, somehow, mistakes doesn't match a `null` to an `Object`.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Read the answer below. The compiler did the right thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add some parenthesis for readability:

```
return (x && y) ? (new Object()) : (x ? x : (y ? y : null));
```

You can see that at `y ? y : null`, the compiler will attempt to unbox `null` (so that the types match), causing a NPE to be thrown.

Comment: to complete : the type of `y : null` is set by `y` because the left operand is null. If you add `(Object) null`, you set the type, preventing the autounboxing to `boolean`, and if you add `Boolean y`, the unboxing is not needed because `null` fits into the `Boolean` type.

Comment: after testing, the NPE apparently happens at `(x ? x : ...)` because the compiler thinks the result of `(y ? y : null)` must be a `boolean`

Comment: @njzk2 This may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882095/booleans-conditional-operators-and-autoboxing if we will treat `(y ? y : null)` as equivalent of `returnsNull()` (but I didn't read it yet so I may be wrong).

Comment: @Pshemo: It seems to be exactly the same issue, yes! (with extra explanation)

Comment: Note that casting explicitly stops any kind of autoboxing, and that the rules of ternary operators are distinct from if-else statements. Even without the weird autoboxing rules for autoboxed primitives, we could see a similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

(this code is unreadable and probably should be avoided.) but to actually answer:
As above, the reasoning has to do with autoboxing and unboxing and the compiler doing checks. It's as if you had written `boolean b = (Boolean) null` which at runtime will throw a NPE.

In example A, you cast it to an Object explicitly, so there is no autoboxing added.

In example B, everything is an object already (boolean is a primitive, while Boolean is an object), so again, no boxing or unboxing.

Finally, in example C there's no unboxing at all, and instead the result is just boxed up when it is returned. (if-else branching allows the compiler to check each branch individually, instead of ternary operators which require figuring out the entirety of the statement and then assigning the entire statement a type. This has to do with statements vs expressions and a whole lot of weirdness in the Java autoboxing and type-checking rules.)

(Casting problems happen at compile-time if you try an incompatible cast like: `(Boolean) 7` or at runtime if you do something like:

```
int c = 7;
Object co = (Object) c;
Boolean bco = (Boolean) co;
```