# Why wrapped type unboxed instead of boxing the primitive?

Tags: java, jvm, javac

I've read the following question [Booleans, conditional operators and autoboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3882095/5067264). I am wondering why wrapped types unboxed to primitives instead of boxing the primitives to wrappers. Is this just a performance optimization?

### Details

The type of conditional expression below is boolean. And there is a hidden NPE.
Third operand (`b1`) of the expression unboxed (throws NPE) and immediately reboxed (if there is no exception).

```
Boolean b1 = null;
Boolean b2 = null != b1 ? false : b1;
```

Instead of this, second operand (primitive false value) can be boxed to Boolean.FALSE. The question is, why the first way is preferred?

Explanations about the type of conditional expressions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

> - If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and    the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion
>     (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.

Comment: You mean, it was a wrong design decision? You probably would have liked to see a coercion to the _expected_ result type of `b2`. That would introduce a far more complex parsing, like in `A ? (a ? b : c) : D`. But that is partially done for generics and lambda expressions. Be happy for simple rules.

Comment: @JoopEggen Actually I didn't mean that it was a wrong design decision, asked to learn the reason of it. If you have an answer, could you explain it?

Comment: Oh, in that case: a primitive type value is more operational than the corresponding wrapper object, hence for balancing two then-else types one would pick the primitive type as target (motivation for the rule cited above). Java simply did not start as a pure OO language but retained primitive non-Object types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this scenario:

```
 Boolean b1 = new Boolean(false); //I know you shouldn't be doing this but it's valid
 boolean foo = b1 == false;
 Boolean bar = b1 == false;
```

Now if things worked like you probably expect them to be, `foo` would be true and `bar` would be false. Or, alternatively both could be false but that would mean autoboxing everything all the time if just a single boxed primitive occurs in the expression. (And then potentially unboxing it for the assignment.)

I wouldn't consider that a good trade-off. Granted, dealing with NPEs from unboxing conversions is ugly but it's something you have to do anyway in most unboxing scenarios.