# Java syntax if and else function

Tags: java, if-statement

This may be a very stupid question, but what does this line in java mean?

```
Seat tempSeat = rowClass ? allSeatsC[i][j] : allSeatsE[i][j];
```

I know it has something to do with an if function but I was trying to re-write it with if. But I just cannot figure out how does it work.

Comment: This is called the conditional operator. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615498/java-conditional-operator-result-type for more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question mark and colon mean in statement? what does it mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957214/question-mark-and-colon-mean-in-statement-what-does-it-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?` is a ternary operator.

It is similar to an if-else statement, but it would return the expression between the `?` and the `:`, if the first expression is true, otherwise, it returns the last expression.

```
Seat tempSeat = rowClass ? allSeatsC[i][j] : allSeatsE[i][j];
```

is equivalent to

```
Seat tempSeat;
if(rowClass){
    tempSeat = allSeatsC[i][j];
}else{
    tempSeat = allSeatsE[i][j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Seat tempSeat;
if(rowClass)
    tempSeat=allSeatsC[i][j];
else
    tempSeat=allSeatsE[i][j]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its called a ternary or "elvis" operator.  Basically an in-line if statement

More info:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java (link gets broken by formatter)

These are really handy for simple tests like the one above.