# Quick explanation of code line

Tags: c#, vector

```
motion *= (Mathf.Abs(inputVec.x) == 1)?.7f:1;
```

as far as i know, the line means, that variable motion gets multiplied by the absolute value of x part of vector inputVec, but i don't understand what happens next.

Comment: It's a conditional operator. if (condition) then `.7f` else `1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java conditional operator ?: result type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615498/java-conditional-operator-result-type)

Answer (score 3):

If the condition `Mathf.Abs(inputVec.x) == 1` is true, then `motion` is multiplied by .7f. Otherwise by 1.

The question mark is the conditional operator. It is a compact way to write an if else statement.

For, instance this:

```
if(Mathf.Abs(inputVec.x) == 1)
{
    motion *= .7f;
}
else
{
    motion *= .5f; 
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
motion *= (Mathf.Abs(inputVec.x) == 1)?.7f:.5f;
```

So you can write one line of code instead of 8 !

Comment: The more proper term is _conditional operator_. _Ternary_ just means that the operator takes three operands.

Answer (score 2):

- the `?:`operator is a short way for a `if`/`else` it's called [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- the `*=` operator is the shortcut for `x = x * 1`, explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/s2bkaksf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- `Math.Abs()` returns the [absolute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.math.abs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) value for a given value
- `0.7f` - the `f` is a [suffix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b1e65aza.aspx) that declares the value as a float type

so..

```
motion *= (Mathf.Abs(inputVec.x) == 1)?.7f:1;
```

equals

```
if (Mathf.Abs(inputVec.x) == 1)) //if inputVec.x equals 1 or -1
{
    motion = motion * 0.7;
}
else
{
    motion = motion * 1;
}
```